# Using generic List as a varargs parameters

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions, generic-collections

I'm trying to implement a generic Tree.

Each Tree has a `value`, a `parent` and a list of its `children`.
Children are added using following method:

```
public Tree<T> addChildren(Tree<T>... children) {
    for (Tree<T> child: children) {
        if (this.children.add(child)) {
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

The problem begins when I have a `List` of Trees I want to add as a children:

```
List<Tree<T>> newChildren;
```

Since [there is no way to create array of parametrized type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays) in Java, the most obvious solution is to iterate over list and add children one by one:

```
for (Tree<T> newChild: newChildren) {
   myTree.addChildren(newChild);
}
```

But this is not an efficient use of varargs. Since I want to keep `Tree` class as simple as possible, is there any other way to implement this ?

Comment: Why don't you create a function that accepts a list of Trees?

Comment: @cy3er Because I want to keep this class as simple as possible.

Comment: I guess adding a method that accepts a list is as simple as it gets. It's certainly the simplest approach I could come up with, and when it comes to readability / testability I definitely favour two distinct methods for two different things (adding children and adding trees). As you mention _efficiency_: It's not getting any better than O(n) :)

Comment: @jangroth Yeah, I mean 'efficient' not in the terms of time complexity, but clean code.

Comment: You can try to call `newChildren.toArray(new Tree<T>[newChildren.size()])` method and pass it as vararg parameter

Comment: @SimY4 Well, this is the problem. You cannot create a generic array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily solved by creating array of raw type:

```
Tree<String>[] newChildrenArray = new Tree[newChildren.size()];
newChildrenArray.toArray(newChildren);
myTree.addChildren(newChildrenArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way for a method to accept both `array` and `List` (or even better, `Iterable`) is to use the `Arrays.asList()` in the array version to call the iterable version. Example:

```
public Tree<T> addChildren(Iterable<Tree<T>> children) { //for lists and collections
    // same code
}

public Tree<T> addChildren(Tree<T>... children) { //for arrays and varargs
    return addAll(Arrays.asList(children));
}
```

Also don't be afraid to use some [wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), if you want to allow a `Tree<Animal>` to have a `Tree<Cat>` as a child, then you would need to change your singatures to:

```
Tree<T> addAll(Iterable<? extends Tree<? extends T>> children) { ... }

Tree<T> addAll(Tree<? extends T>... children) { ... }
```

Comment: Using current implementation of addChildren(), I cannot use wildcards.

Comment: As I said, that would be needed only if you wanted a `Tree<SuperType>` to have `Tree<SubType>` as a child, and that would require some more changes, or might be even impossible, depending on what you want to do with the children. But *always* use wildcards in read-only or write-only structures, like `Iterable<? extends Tree<T>> children`, that should work fine with current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method accepting a `List`, and have one of your methods calling the other:

```
public Tree<T> addChildren(Iterable<Tree<T>> children) {
    for (Tree<T> child : children) {
        if (this.children.add(child)) {
            child.setParent(this);
        }
    }
    return this;
}

public Tree<T> addChildren(Tree<T>... children) {
    return addChildren(Arrays.asList(children));
}
```